# Why does MakerBot software shows holes in the wall of a 3d model?

Tags: 3d-models, makerbot, makerware

I made a simple extrude on a sketch in Fusion 360:

[image: Fusion 360 extrude]

But what MakerBot software shows me in the preview is

[image: MakerBot preview of extrude]

Can someone explain how to make it print a smooth wall? Mesh of the model also seems to be okay. Configuration is in the high preset.

Comment: Are you confusing infill patterns with holes?  Or display resolution (moire pattern) with actual surfaces?  What is your head speed setting,  layer thickness, etc?

Comment: What are your software settings? This could be anyting without proper information as we could not recreate this.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't know how to call it. I am talking about leftmost part which is different from the pattern of the rest of the wall (face looking at the camera)

Comment: @Trish what properties do you need? I set default High preset

Comment: the most interesting would be: Version number of the software you use, Layer height. Wall thickness. Infill density. Infill pattern. What type of bed adhesion helper (is that a raft?). Material. Then a little Information about your model: if it is hollow or solid in design? It might help if you upload your STL so we can look if that is faulty for some reason, but if it is just a simple extrusion as said, that should not be the case unless the file is corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the corner of the part facing you in the first figure, and the sliced corner on the left in the second figure and not the white lines on the wall facing you. This latter effect is called [Moiré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) or moiré pattern which is an optical illusion created by interference.

This appears to be a slicer error or a rendering error, the walls are not finished. Furthermore from your sparse question it is noteworthy to say that you have sliced the model on a raft.

Why not print the model, it will start a raft and when you come to the part it will clearly show whether it is a slicing or a rendering problem!

If it is a rendering problem, keep continuing printing, if not, stop the print and download a most recent version of any other free available slicer tool. The most commonly used free slicer tools are [Ultimaker Cura](https://ultimaker.com/) and [Slic3r](http://slic3r.org). Setup a printer profile and select and modify material and slicing properties to create a new G-code file for you to print. You can now compare the rendering of used new tool to your current rendering and print the model to see if the part now prints well.